# Is it possible to make a names of the tables in the database as a methods of my class?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am very like to use PDO, so it might be on.

Usage could be as:

```
$m = new MDB();

$m->Users()->GetRec($param);
```

`Users()` is a name of table in the database, `GetRec($param)` is my function.

A way I go looking like this:

```
class MDB extends DB {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        if ($result = $this->pdo->query("SHOW TABLES"))
        {

            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
            {
                // this is only my imagination (not working at all)
                __set($row[0],true);

            }

        }

    }

    // set
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        // here could be a method (not properties)
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
```

Sure it's all seems not exactly what I want. So I am able to get some suggestions and advices in this question.

**upd** 1.

Thanks for the magic method __call and now I'm trying to make it within. Watch my updated code:

```
class MDB extends DB {

    function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

}

public function __call( $method, $param )
{

    $tables = array();

    if ($result = $this->pdo->query("SHOW TABLES"))
    {

        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
        {

            $tables[] = $row[0];

        }

    }

    if (in_array($method,$tables))
    {

        return $this;

    }
    else
    {

        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

Well, seems it works for me!

Comment: Take a look at the [magical __call method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Comment: though it can danger if the method already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible! The wrong row in your code is:

```
__set($row[0],true);
```

There you should call:

```
$this->$row[0] = true;
```

Take a look a the simple example below and at the overloading documentation of PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php.

```
class A{

//The array which will contain your data
private $tables;

function __construct($array){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($array as $value){
        //That's the right call!    
        $this->$value = $counter++;
    }
}


function __set($name, $value){
    $this->tables[$name] = $value;
}

function __get($name){
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->tables)) {
           return $this->tables[$name];
    }
}

}

$array = array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5');
$a = new A($array);

foreach($array as $key){
    echo $a->$key;
}
```

Hope this help!